# Why does specifying table alias force Postgres to do a nested loop + seq scan?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Given a table containing a few hundred records with a `venueId` non-unique indexed UUID column and a `number` column which is uniquely incrementing per each `venueId` and running these two queries in order to get the highest `number` for a given `venueId`, which at first glance should be functionally identical:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT MAX("order"."number") as "number" 
FROM "order" "Order", "order" "order" 
WHERE "order"."venueId" = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457';

EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT MAX("number") as "number" 
FROM "order" 
WHERE "venueId" = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457';
```

The result is a significantly different execution plan and horrendously worse performance on the former query as it results in a full seq scan:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=52151.44..52151.45 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=912.437..912.437 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..43500.01 rows=3460574 width=5) (actual time=0.013..529.481 rows=3608550 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on order Order  (cost=0.00..116.71 rows=2171 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.722 rows=2187 loops=1)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..130.11 rows=1594 width=5) (actual time=0.000..0.088 rows=1650 loops=2187)
              ->  Seq Scan on order  (cost=0.00..122.14 rows=1594 width=5) (actual time=0.003..0.621 rows=1650 loops=1)
                    Filter: (venueId = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457'::uuid)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 537
Planning Time: 0.082 ms
Execution Time: 912.474 ms
```

Compared to the latter which behaves as expected with just an index scan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=72.58..72.59 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using "IDX_0a24b2daada45c3eccdaaeb67c" on "order"  (cost=0.28..72.57 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("venueId" = '0efd1e7e-33f7-4cca-a06e-5a2ecbcc6447'::uuid)
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.087 ms
Execution Time: 0.083 ms
```

Why is it that the `FROM "order" "Order", "order" "order"` table aliasing (which was being generated by my ORM which I've worked around to remove) seems to prevent Postgres from using the index correctly as intended?

Comment: One query does a self join and the other does not do any joins.  That is not just a difference in aliases.

Comment: `FROM "order" "Order", "order" "order"` is the same as `FROM "order" as "Order" cross join "order" as "order"` - did you really intend that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of several good reasons for using explicit "Join" syntax instead of the [more compact] "Comma" syntax.
Let's re-write your poorly performing query and see if we can spot a difference.  Here's the original:

```
SELECT MAX("order"."number") as "number" 
FROM "order" "Order", "order" "order" 
WHERE "order"."venueId" = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457';
```

Looks innocent enough, at first glance, but let's apply a little editing:

```
SELECT MAX("order"."number") AS "number" 
FROM "order" "Order"
INNER JOIN "order" "order" 
WHERE "order"."venueId" = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457';
```

Notice that third line!
You include the **order** table twice, under two *different* correlation names ("Order" and "order") but you specify no *join condition* between these two tables.  The database will evaluate a Cartesian Product (a.k.a. [very] Cross Join) between the **order** table and *itself*, matching *every* row against *every other* row, and then filtering *that* result based on venueId.

Is it any *wonder* it's struggling?

Some advice:

- *Lose* the double quotes.  As a rule, you should never *need* to use them around *any* table or column name.  If you do, then you're fighting the database's natural behaviour and, at some point, it *will* turn around and bite you.
- Use correlation names for tables.
- Use proper, long-winded (maybe) but far more *understandable*, join syntax.

As an *example*, you might get something like this:

```
SELECT MAX( o1.order_number) AS order_number 
FROM order o1 
INNER JOIN order o2 
      ON o1.old_order_number = o2.order_number 
WHERE o1.venueId = '4fd146df-81fd-44e0-b6d8-3bad94f76457';
```

Answer (score 1):

These queries are substantially different.

The first one contains a cross join of `order` with itself: each result row in `order` will be paired with each row in `Order`, which will result in n times as many result rows, where n is the number of rows in `Order`. You don't notice that, because your table contains only one row.

You probably did something wrong with your ORM to get the first query.